# IOS VoiP push doesn't work with APNS push

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, callkit, pushkit

I have a project which use VoiP pushes for calling and APNS pushes for simple notifications. APNS push comes, but VoiP doesn't come. When server tries to send me VoiP push by my VoiP token server throws exception "Invalid Token". Please, see my solution and let me know what I do worst.

[I created two certificates (APNS and VoiP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owY3k.png)

[I added certificate to identify, but I can add just APNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZDwc.png)

Next, I generated **p12** keys and send to server for using them.

In UIApplicationDelegate I retrieve APNS token and send to server

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    
    //next send APNS token
}
```

APNS token I receive successful here

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```

VoiP push notification I register at first

```
    func registerForPushVoipNotifications() {
    let voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    voipRegistry.delegate = self
    voipRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
}
```

Here I receive VoiP push token

```
    public func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
    let token:String? = credentials.token.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
    //send VoiP token to server
}
```

By documentation sending VoiP push I must to receive here

```
    func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

But when server sends VoiP push it gets error **Invalid Token**. What do I worst?

Comment: Is it related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67308054/sendemptypushnotification-to-gateway-push-apple-com-no-longer-working/67309911?noredirect=1#comment118996327_67309911

Comment: Also make sure that BE sends notification with '.voip' suffix to bundle id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73266286/745161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you should use p8 authKey to send push notifications
- Secondly, PKPushRegistry is stored in the func? This is strange. Move it to field of your class
- Thirdly, try converting the token from data by the following code:

  ```
    class TokenConverter {

        static func token(from data: Data) -> String {

            let tokenParts = data.map { data -> String in
                return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
            }

            return tokenParts.joined()
        }
    }
  ```